# Oracle connections where username has $?

Tags: asp.net, oracle, connection, oracle11g

I need help tracking something down, I'm getting several connections where in Enterprise Manager it says:

```
OS User Name: Example$ <-- Example is the machine name.
Terminal: Example
Machine: Domain\Example
```

There is NO user named Example$, where is this coming from?....

I'm using Oracle 11g.

**Edit:** 
The problem I'm tracking is with an asp.net app that keeps connections open, I'm using the "using" statement everytime I open them, so that's not it. It seems to be a problem with the connection pooling.

Answer (score 2):

MachineName$ is the Network Service account of a machine called MachineName, as seen from some other machine.

/Klaus

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you mean sessions? An open session is not neccesarily the same thing as an open connection.

Perhaps this isn't really a problem. The [connection pooling mechanism](http://www.developer.com/db/article.php/3729831/Using-Connection-Pooling-in-ADONET.htm) means that [although you may close/dispose your use of connections, they remain in the pool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254502.aspx) for efficiency reasons for rapid re-use so that may explain why you see some Oracle sessions still alive. This is probably a good thing and a rational DBA won't have too many complaints about that.

Answer (score 0):

It is a user that is externally authenticated via the OS.